# Get textarea value having linebreaks in Javascript variable using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a textarea having text with linebreaks (enter key). I am assigning the textarea content to a Javascript variable using PHP as following:

```
var textareaContent = '<?php echo trim( $_POST['textarea'] ) ?>';
```

Example content in textarea:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

Which is generating following Javascript error because of the line breaks:

```
Unterminated string literal
```

I tried using `nl2br` function in PHP which places `<br/>` tag in each line break but line breaks are still there and so the Javascript error.

Please advise

Comment: You're sure PHP doesn't print those as \n, and that the issue is something else? When posting the values to the server, the strings are usually escaped.

Comment: These line breaks are because of the enter key pressed in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like this:

```
var textareaContent = '<?php echo trim(preg_replace("/\n/", '\n', $_POST['textarea'])); ?>';
```

this code will chanhe all line breaks to escape sequence \n

Comment: which OS do you use? i guess win?
anyway i have modified my example to make it work in any OS (actually problem is in line-endings, e.g. \n or \r or \r\n)

`var textareaContent = '<?php echo trim(preg_replace("/\r?\n/", '\n', $_POST['textarea'])); ?>';`

Comment: I am using windows 7. Still the issue is there. There isn't any `\r\n` or `\n` in the textarea content being get using `$_POST['textarea']`. So there is nothing to replace.

Comment: @RajatVarlani, emmmm, wat? :) you just wrote about 'line breaks' and now you tell me that there isn't any \n or \r\n (what is obviously present or what line breaks we are talking about) ?

Comment: just to be clear:
1. code http://clip2net.com/s/71vGkK
2. result http://clip2net.com/s/71vHbs
3. source code of result http://clip2net.com/s/71vHWV